# Get values for global variables without reading file again

Tags: java, scala, oop, constructor

This is the code structure:

```
case class Demo(path:String){
  private val df: DataFrame = read()
  var a = df.columns(0)
  var b = df.columns(1)
  var str = df.select("some").toJSON
  def read(): DataFrame {/* code to read from path and return a dataframe*/}
}
```

This is a poor way of reading the global variables as they depend on the value of `df`. I want to remove this dependency , but at the same time, not call the read method three times.

In Java, I would call the read method in a constructor and define the values of the global variables there. How can I do the same thing in Scala? It seems I cannot call the `read` method from an auxiliary constructor. Any other/better approach is also welcome.

Comment: What is wrong with putting the read logic when declaring the `df` **val**, and changing all those **vars** to **vals** ? - I think I don't understand your question well, may you explain if I am missing something?, also in **Scala** the body of the class is its constructor, thus... no much different from what you would do in **Java**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez the problem with this is that the line where `df` is defined, always needs to be above `a`,`b` and `str`. I have a plugin which refactors `df` some lines below and then I get a NullPointerException during runtime.

Comment: @smaug change `val df` to `lazy val df`. Then it can be defined anywhere

Comment: You should file a bug against the autoformatter and/or stop using it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I had never been a fan of *auto-format* tools, I have always tough formating is part of the developers job *(especially if they can mess the code, then something is wrong)*.

However, leaving outside my opinions, you can either pass `df` as an argument to your `Demo` **class**.
You can create a *factory* in the **companion object** of `Demo`so you don't have to change your code.

```
final class Demo(df: DataFrame) {
  val a = df.columns(0)
  val b = df.columns(1)
  val str = df.select("some").toJSON
}
object Demo extends (String => Demo) {
  private def read(path: String): DataFrame = {/* code to read from path and return a dataframe*/}

  override def apply(path: String): Demo = new Demo(df = read(path))
}
```

*(I made it a normal **class** instead, because I don't see any reason for it to be a **case class** - you can change that if you like)*.

Other option, would be to use `lazy vals`, which will defer the evaluation of them until access.
However, I believe the above would be the best.

```
final class Demo(path:String) {
  lazy val a = df.columns(0)
  lazy val b = df.columns(1)
  lazy val str = df.select("some").toJSON

  def read(): DataFrame = {/* code to read from path and return a dataframe*/}

  private val df: DataFrame = read()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I am reluctant to define read in a companion object because if I have to extend `Demo` later, I would have to redefine `read`. Please correct me if I am wrong. Also, could you explain what is happening here: `object class extends (String => Demo)`. I can't compile it.

Comment: @smaug oh sorry, it is `object Demo extends (String => Demo)` , the `extends (String => Demo)` is to make the object a function from **String** to **Demo**, you may omit it if you never plan to use it as a function _(you would need to remove the `override` from the definition of `apply` too)_. Well if you plan to extend `Demo` you may need to remove the `final` _(and then it must not be a case class)_, and you may move read to other part... why exactly would you want to extend Demo later?